# Efficient Way to Get All Values From Hash With Key Less Than a Certain Value

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

We collect data from 10 sources every second.  I'm trying to think of a way to store the data in memory that would allow me to get data like "Every point of data from 12:01 to 12:02".

I've thought about using a tree of some sort or a sorted list.  The key would be the time collected and the value would be an array of the measurements.  I can't think of how to say "Give me all values for keys in this range".  I can only think to use the sorted nature of these structures to quickly get the values for a certain key.

Will I need to calculate the appropriate keys (12:01:00, 12:01:01, ..., 12:01:59) and pull each of those values independently or is there some way I can utilize a sorted data structure to get all my data at once?

Comment: [Redis](http://redis.io), [VoltDB](http://voltdb.com/), [Daybreak](http://propublica.github.io/daybreak/)...

Comment: I thought Redis was only a key/value store. Is there some extra functionality to operate on the keys?

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't what you want is just a range query, right ? Any sorted data structure can give you that, if you store data in a sorted array why you can's just query give me all the element between 12:01--12:05 ?  But since you clearly need insert a lot, I would suggest you to use B+ tree.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't think of how to do a range query on a sorted data structure.  Given a list of keys, I could easily grab the appropriate values one at a time, but I can't think of how to do that in one fell swoop

Comment: Yes, Redis is more of a data structure server. Even the keys can be data structures. It supports hashes, lists, sets, etc. In your case you probably want a sorted set. You can do a ZRANGE query to get values for keys in a certain range.

Comment: WTF ignore my answer. I thought this was a Python question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with a ruby Hash, and there isn't an easy way to implement it yourself. You would have to implement a binary tree/B-tree/redblack tree along with a nice API for doing range queries.

My suggestion would be to use an in-memory sqlite database. Then you can query it with familiar sql grammar. Sqlite is a very well done project and I imagine will be very space and time efficient.

```
require 'sqlite3'
@db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
@db.execute <<-SQL
  create table records(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    timestamp integer,
    data text
  );
SQL
@db.execute <<-SQL
  select * from records where ...
SQL
```

Read about sqlite data types here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html